# How to find max in the list of data frames

Tags: r

I have several input data files in my working dir, I would like to read all input data and find one MAX value of all values stored in those files. Here is the code:

```
##. identify files to read in
filesToProcess  <- (Sys.glob("*.csv"))
filesToProcess 

## Read all file and store in a list
listOfFiles <- lapply(filesToProcess, function(x) read.table(x, header = FALSE))

max(listOfFiles) #-- error
```

Can anyone give me suggestion how to get the MAX? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How about `max(unlist(listOfFiles))` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `max` operation is not defined for a list of `data.frame`'s, only for vectors of numbers. To get the max value of all values, you can simply use:

```
max(unlist(listOfFiles))
```

where `unlist` recursively reduces the list of `data.frame`'s to one vector of numbers.

Comment: Can you give an example? In my case, the unlist is transforming strings inside dataframe to numbers. How will you avoid that?